# How should I create a realistic landscape based on a real place?

Tags: modeling, materials, photorealism

I'm making a short film about a flying carpet, and the background plate for the green screen needs to be CG.

I have this model based off terrain data of the actual location taken from Open Street Map:[image]

And I need to make it look kind of like this, except photorealistic:
[image]

What's the best way to do this? I'm using Cycles by the way. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a quite long task to do.

First you'll also need some texturing for the ground.

Then you'll need to have the models of all the building, then texture every one of them. Then the same thing for the roads and so on...

Their is an addon call blenderGiS (https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS) which can take care of importing google data, i.e. building (the one google knows the shape) and road (it import the road a curves i believe).

This solve partially the problem of how to get all the 3D model in blender. However, you'll have to do some modelling for the road or if you want very realistic building model since google has only the very low poly models of building.

Then you need to texture everything.... So good luck !

Comment: I'm thinking of using a particle system for the buildings, and open street map has road textures. How would you recommend texturing the mountain?

Comment: One thing you can do is use the satelite image from google earth as a texture for your ground. I did that for texturing a city, it works quite well. You just need to align the texture with your ground)